# Looking into Chrome DevTools looking for an address

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry for the question but i am new.

When a look with chrome developer tools the addres is "short"

```
<area shape="rect" coords="441,105,521,124" href="obra.asp?lng=es" alt="Castellano">
<area shape="rect" coords="543,105,596,123" href="obra.asp?lng=en" alt="Inglés">
<area shape="rect" coords="616,106,680,123" href="obra.asp?lng=fr" alt="Francés">
```

But when i look in the shame code with sublime text it look like this.

```
<area shape="rect" coords="441,105,521,124" href="obrab64c.html?lng=es" alt="Castellano">
<area shape="rect" coords="543,105,596,123" href="obra6dc5.html?lng=en" alt="Inglés">
<area shape="rect" coords="616,106,680,123" href="obraa154.html?lng=fr" alt="Francés">
```

Would be possible to access to the full address with chrome developer tools?